# MYSQL tables shows empty when import

Tags: mysql

On windows, using MAMP, I did a dump of my database (foo_db) with `mysqldump`. I placed the file on a usb memory stick and copy/paste to my ubuntu 18 desktop. Has mysql installed I did changed dir to where the sql file is and ran

```
mysql -u root -p db_name < foo_dump.sql
```

Nothing happens which is expected that when finished I get cursor to do whatever again. Logging into mysql I did `show databases` I saw just one. After the import I saw two; the other was of the db name of the database I exported from (`foo_db`). Why? `db_name` is empty when I specifically imported into it?

Comment: have you have create the db_name schema in your mysql?

Comment: @PaolaG Yes I did with `create database db_name;`

Comment: try to add at your command: `-h localhost` before the db_name

Comment: What options you used for `mysqldump`? `foo_db` appearing in ubuntu mysql instance prompts that your dump contains `create database foo_db` statement in it and dump data is loaded into this `foo_db`. You likely need to add `--no-create-db` option to `mysqldump`.